# How to forcefully shrink overflow of child elements inside a div tag

Tags: javascript, css

I have this below HTML code.

```
<div id="ImageWrapper" class="grid_col-xs">

  <div id="parentID" style="background-image: url(img/retailshop.jpg);background-size:100%;width: 100%;height: 0;padding-top: 66.64%;" ></div>                              

  <script type="text/javascript">
        drawOverlayHeatmap('parentID');
  </script>

</div>
```

`drawOverlayHeatmap('parentID')` function draws a canvas inside the `parentID` div tag. But it overflows some content out of my div tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var X = new Array(10, 10, 10, 30, 10, 30, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 50, 60, 70, 80);
        var Y = new Array(10, 30, 10, 50, 10, 50, 30, 20, 10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 100, 10, 10, 10, 100);
        var C = new Array(5, 10, 7, 20, 5, 20, 5, 10, 7, 20, 5, 20, 5, 10, 7, 20, 5, 20);
        var computeRelativePosition = (point, relativeTo) => {
            return (point / 100) * relativeTo;
        };

        function drawOverlayHeatmap(elementName){

            var heatmap = h337.create({
                container: document.getElementById(elementName),
                // a waterdrop gradient ;-)
                // gradient: { .1: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 0.25: "rgba(0,0,90, .6)", .6: "blue", .9: "cyan", .95: 'rgba(255,255,255,.4)' },
                maxOpacity: .6,
                radius: 10,
                blur: .90
            });

            var width = (window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(elementName)).width.replace(/px/, ''));
            var height = (window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(elementName)).height.replace(/px/, ''));
            console.log(height);

            var generate = function (iterator) {

                var x = (computeRelativePosition(X[iterator], width)) >> 0;
                var y = (computeRelativePosition(Y[iterator], height)) >> 0;
                var c = (C[iterator] * 100) >> 0;

                // add the datapoint to heatmap instance
                heatmap.addData({ x: x, y: y, value: c, radius: 50 });
            };
            for (i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
                generate(i);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

How can I forcefully set my dic tag not to let other components inside it to overflow?

**EDIT:** I have tried to use `overflow: auto` and `hidden`. But I don't want to lose the overflow area. I want that area to be shrink and fir on my `parentID` div tag.

I'm using the https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/ to draw the heatmaps above the images. I have put the image as my background in the div tag.

Comment: Change `overflow: auto;` to `overflow: hidden`

Comment: You have now made it unclear what you are after - you want to hide overflow from your div but allow it? doesn't make any sense

Comment: @Pete I don't want to hide anything. I want to shrink

Comment: ok then this is too broad a question for this site.  but what you would need to do is figure out how much overflow there is and then either use transform scale or zoom to shrink your content by the required amount

Comment: Based on your edit, you need to update the rest of the code as well, so we get a working code snippet, or else there is no way to help you

Comment: @LGSon I have added, now anyone can give it a try. :)